# Unable to view xml in android studio (render problem)

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

I am getting rendering issues in my app. Although the app is working good on design mode, I am getting below errors on all `XML's`

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:359)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.themifyContext(AppCompatViewInflater.java:336)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:91)
... 23 more
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I got once something like this error. When i have closed and reopen the project. It started to show all xml's again. I'm not sure totally that i understand you.